# NPM - all actions fail with similar error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

While trying to do a routinely npm install (NPM worked in this computer until today) I started getting this error repeatedly:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${version}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:418:13
    at String.replace (<anonumous>)
    at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:414:12)
    at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:392:7)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:17
    at Array.ForEach (<anonumous>)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:334:23)
    at ConfigChain.addEnv (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:207:15)
    at Conf.addEnv (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:359:30)
    at load_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:107:8)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:51
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:51:13)
    at process.ErrorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:374:26)
```

I have tried deleting .npmrc, downgrading nodeJS, reinstalling and nothing works... anyone knows what causes this?